# Campo Text en control de usuario personalizado como en el TextBox

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy haciendo un control de usuario personalizado.

```
    public class MiControl:UserControl
    {
       public string _Cadena{get;set;} = "";
       ...
    }
```

Lo añado a un windows.forms y en la ventana de propiedades me muestra esta para poder asignarle un valor.

Me gustaría que en tiempo de diseño y al situarme en esta propiedad se comportara como cuando me sitúo en la propiedad Text de un TextBox. Me permite expandir y mostrar un cuadro para incluir el texto de forma más cómodo.

[image: Propiedad Text de un System.Windows.Forms.TextBox]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los [Atributos de tiempo de diseño para componentes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/aa719950(v=vs.71).aspx) que necesitas agregar:

```
    namespace WFATMP1
    {        

        public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
        {
            [Category("Personalizado")]
            [Description("Propiedad visible en diseño")]
            [Browsable(true)]
[Editor("System.ComponentModel.Design.MultilineStringEditor, System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", typeof(UITypeEditor))]
            public string Propiedad { get; set; }

            public UserControl1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]